# Thunderbird Signature Switch - Sync signatures between different devices

Tags: sync, thunderbird, signature

When composing a message in Thunderbird I would like to easily turn on/off and choose between signatures but also sync my signatures between different devices.

So far the Signature Switch add-on in Thunderbird was perfect for the job. I could save the html files in a synced folder and signatures would update automatically on all devices.

But unfortunately in the newest version of Signature Switch signatures can't be stored in external html-files (except for backup) and syncing between different machines is not possible.

Is there another add-on or a workaround that does the trick?